# Adding Percentage of Number to Itself

Tags: php, math

I want to add 30.4 percent of `$drivervalue` to `$drivervalue`, is it possible to do that as below? I know if I knew what the actual number was going to be I could just put the 30.4 after the 1., but as I wont know what it will be, I am using the variable instead is this a valid syntax?

```
//example

$drivervalue = 16000000;

$percentdiff = 30.4;

$drivvalue *= 1. $percentdiff;
```

Comment: Related: [Percentage a number is of another number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263645/percentage-a-number-is-of-another-number) - Also useful: [PHP Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$drivervalue *= (1 + $percentdiff / 100);
```

Answer (score 23):

```
 $num = 100;
 $percentage = 30.4;
 $num += $num*($percentage/100); // results in 130.4
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$drivervalue = $drivervalue * (1 + ($percentdiff / 100));
```