# Percentage a Number is of Another Number

Tags: php, math

How to find the percentage a number is of another number in PHP?

**Example**

```
$num1 = 2.6;
$num2 = 2.6;
// Should equal to 100%
```

Comment: I'd say this is independent to the programming language somehow and added the [tag:math] tag. Also useful: [PHP Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Divide the two numbers and multiply by 100 to get the percentage:

```
$percentage = ($num1 / $num2) * 100;
echo $percentage . "%";
```

Of course you will need to check so that `$num1` is not 0, something like this: `$percentage = ($num1 !== 0 ? ($num1 / $num2) : 0) * 100;`

Comment: What if $num2 is zero?

Comment: @Piero - I don't think that was the question?

Comment: True, but your answer does not cover all cases, but only the particular one. I don't think user969729 only needs to know percentage 2.6 is of 2.6, do you?

Comment: @Piero - Cover all cases? It answers the following question: `How to find the percentage a number is of another number in PHP` and it seems to me that it were sufficient or else I don't think he would have accepted my answer do you?

Comment: `It answers the following question` - only in case when both numbers are 2.6. That is a very specific situation, and in your answer you could've helped out more people, if you explained the case with zero. The fact, that your answer was accepted, does not mean you couldn't have answered better. Stack Overflow is public not only for the person asking a question, and the one answering it, but to general public, and the more useful the answers are - the better for the community. You did a great job by answering the question, @Krister, but could've done better IMHO.

Comment: @Piero - So, why aren't you telling the person with the second answer the same?

Comment: Well, your answer was accepted, thus you're the one I'm telling it. Although it's the same case with the second answer, and @Tim Cooper should take a not of this too.

Answer (score 9):

```
$percentage = sprintf("%d%%", $num1 / $num2 * 100); // string: 100%
```